# Auto-Py-to-Exe | Signing a Windows EXE file

Tags: python, windows, executable, code-signing-certificate

For the purpose of making a small piece of software for a friend to study I created a little GUI application with pysimplegui. Because he is not really tech-savy and still has a Win7, I tried to pack it as .exe ahead and then also created an installer and gave it via USB to him.
Unfortunately his Anti-Virus pops up and he gets sort of scared and didn't know what to do.
Figured out I could resolve it by signing the code with makecert but have to somehow get the key to be installed on his PC also.

Is there a way to implement that in the installer to spare him going through the technicalities?

I used the Auto-Py-To-Exe application to convert the python file btw and InnoSetup to create the Installer --- Before handing over, I did try it on a clean Windows7 VM and it worked after using the installer (thought the Registry wanted to get it installed properly).

Answer (score -1):

Remove code from your program that may be **harmful**

Then virus detection software should ignore.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).